# Minimum Change Maker Returning Optimal Solution and No Solution

Tags: lua, dynamic-programming

I need Help adding a if clause to my Change Maker, so that if say I have denominations of coins that can't equal the input coin value. *For Example I have Coins worth 2,4,6 and I have a Value of 1.* I Want it to return **Change Not Possible** I tried adding a clause to it below but when I test it I get **1.#INF** 
I also am curious how I can find the optimal coin solution, So on top of saying the minimum number of coins it returns the optimal coin setup if there is one.

```
function ChangeMaking(D,n)
--[[
//Applies dynamic programming to find the minimum number of coins
//of denominations d1< d2 < . . . < dm where d1 = 1 that add up to a
//given amount n
//Input: Positive integer n and array D[1..m] of increasing positive
// integers indicating the coin denominations where D[1]= 1
//Output: The minimum number of coins that add up to n
]]
  F = {} -- F is List Array of Coins
  m = tablelength(D)
  F[0] = 0
  for i =1,n do 
    temp = math.huge
    j = 1
  while j <= m and i >= D[j] do
    temp = math.min(F[ i - D[j] ], temp)
    j = j + 1
  end
  F[i] = temp + 1
  end
  --I wanted to Catch the failed Solution here but I return 1.#INF instead 
  --if F[n] <= 0 and F[n] == 1.#INF then print("No Change Possible") return end
  return F[n]
end

function main()

--[[
//Prints a Greeting, Asks for Denominations separated by spaces.
// Iterates through the input and assigns values to table
// Table is then input into ChangeMaker, and a while loop takes an n value for user input.
// User Enters 0 to end the Loop
]]

  io.write("Hello Welcome the to Change Maker - LUA Edition\nEnter a series of change denominations, separated by spaces: ")
  input = io.read()
  deno = {}
  for num in input:gmatch("%d+") do table.insert(deno,tonumber(num)) end
  local i = 1
  while i ~= 0 do
    io.write("Please Enter Total for Change Maker, When Finished Enter 0 to Exit: ")
    input2 = io.read("*n")
    if input2 ~= 0 then io.write("\nMinimum # of Coins: " .. ChangeMaking(deno,input2).."\n") end
    if input2 == 0 then i=0 print("0 Entered, Exiting Change Maker") end
  end
end
function tablelength(T)
--[[
//Function for grabbing the total length of a table.
]]
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
  return count
end

main()
```

Comment: `if F[n] == math.huge then print("No Change Possible") return end`

Comment: That fixes the return 1.#INF, thank you! Do you know how i can catch the most optimal solution in the change maker?